# Visual Studio 2022 uses decompiled dll instead of my original C# source files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have project A which references project B (C#; .NET Framework 4.8).

```
namespace A {
  public static ClassA {
    public static void CallA() {
      // ClassA of project A calls a method of ClassB of project B.
      B.ClassB.CallB();
    }
  }
}
```

When I click on `CallB()` and click "go to implementation" Visual Studio does not show me the original source file! Visual Studio decompiles B.dll and shows me the decompiled code. Why?

If I rename ClassB I would expect that Visual Studio shows me a failure. But Visual Studio uses the old B.dll and ignores my code changes. Why?

Answer (score 1):

If you see the decompiled source, that means VS was unable to load debug symbols (the .pdb files next to your dlls, or build inside them).

Check the symbol status for your dll, if you set it up correctly it should say "Symbols loaded":

```
'VideoMixer.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
```